# How to test JMS Queues with Robot Framework(RIDE)

Tags: python, selenium, jms, robotframework

I am using robot framework with selenium(Python).I have Installed JMS-Utils-1.0.2 and robotframework-jmslibrary-1.0.0 .But still Not able to access methods of JMS Library.After Importing JMSLibrary it is showing up in Red Color. Please find the screenshot.Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problems in getting the documentation from imported libraries are discussed in the official [Wiki page](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Keyword-Completion).

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the remote server to access this library? Since it is java library, it cannot be directly imported to RED, it has to be imported as a Remote library.